# How to map solr suggest component and request handler XML config properties to JSON config API?

Tags: solr

I'm trying to configure a [suggest search component and request handler](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/suggester.html) via [Config API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/config-api.html#how-to-map-solrconfig-xml-properties-to-json) and I need to map the XML config properties to JSON Config API request.

XML config for suggest search component:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
        <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="field">suggestTerm</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_suggest</str>
        <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

XML config for suggest request handler:

```
<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="suggest">true</str>
        <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
        <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
        <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

Suggest search component JSON representation in Config API:

```
{
    "add-searchcomponent": {
        "name": "suggest",
        "class": "solr.SuggestComponent",
        "defaults": {
            "name": "mySuggester",
            "lookupImpl": "FuzzyLookupFactory",
            "dictionaryImpl": "DocumentDictionaryFactory",
            "field": "suggestTerm",
            "suggestAnalyzerFieldType": "text_suggest"
        }
    }
}
```

Suggest search handler JSON representation in Config API:

```
{
    "add-requesthandler": {
        "name": "/suggest",
        "class": "solr.SearchHandler",
        "startup": "lazy",
        "defaults": {
            "suggest": true,
            "suggest.count": 10,
            "suggest.dictionary": "mySuggester",
        },
        "components": [
            "suggest"
        ]
    }
}
```

I've tried the suggest handler but I'm getting this error:

```
"No suggester named mySuggester was configured"
```

Here's my current config retrieved from Config API:

https://gist.github.com/stevenferrer/076f3074b376897086cf8a1bd5dbbf79

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the search component part. I accidentally copied the example from [Config API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/config-api.html#how-to-map-solrconfig-xml-properties-to-json)

```
{
    "add-searchcomponent": {
        ...
        "defaults": { // this is the issue
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The correct config is:

```
"add-searchcomponent": {
    "name": "suggest",
    "class": "solr.SuggestComponent",
    "suggester": { // from 'default' to 'suggester'
        "name": "mySuggester",
        "lookupImpl": "FuzzyLookupFactory",
        "dictionaryImpl": "DocumentDictionaryFactory",
        "field": "suggest",
        "suggestAnalyzerFieldType": "text_suggest"
    }
}
```